# Mongodb store sales data by month schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How should I defined my schema if I want to retrieve/insert monthly sales figure? like this?

```
sales: [{
Jan:Number,
Feb:Number
}]
```

Comment: Well it depends, what happens next year? If you want to keep data separated by year, then you need to include 'year' field.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly define a schema for such aggregates, running just the aggregation operation on the `Sale` model (if defined with fields such as the sale timestamp and the product(s)) should give you the desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simply create a schema as following

```
var monthlySale = new Schema({ 
   sale: Number, 
   month: Number, //may be string
   year: Number
});

var MonthlySale = mongoose.model('MonthlySale', monthlySale);
```

and you can insert

```
var sale = new MonthlySale({ sale: 5000, month: 7, year: 2016})
sale.save(function(err, saleObj) {
    if(err) 
       console.log('Unable to create sale')
    else
       console.log('New sale created')
});
```

and you may find as following

```
MonthlySale.findOne({month: 7, year: 2016}, function(err, sale) {
    if(err) 
       console.log('Unable to fetch sale')
    else
       console.log('Sale : ', sale)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use values as field name in mongodb schema, that makes it hard to query on it. It is upto you what data you want to save, you can save date of each month of the year, or save month and year field separately.

Below are two schema I think you can use.

```
sales:[
    {
        month_date: {type: Date},
        amount: {type: Number}
    }
]


sales:[
    {
        month: {type: String},
        year: {type: Number},
        amount: {type: Number}
    }
]
```

With these schema you can easily query on these records

Comment: my question has nothing to do with validation

Answer (score 0):

You can use joi validation, here is an example... (Note: i'm making it dynamic by exporting it so that you can use anywhere you want to...)

So, you have to import joi module first. See below...

```
var joi = require('joi');
```

Now below is the validators of string, number etc...

```
var string = joi.string().min(2).max(50); //you can also set max,min..
var bool = joi.boolean();
var number = joi.number().min(1).max(999999999).required();   
var object = function object(obj) {
      return joi.object().keys(obj);
    }        
var array = function array(ary) {
      return joi.array().items(ary).min(1);
    }
```

Now just export these all...

```
module.exports = {
  string: string,
  bool: bool,
  number: number,
  object: object,
  array: array
}
```

And now you can import the file in which you kept it and can use these validators.

```
var schema = { 
   firstname: string.label('user firstname'), 
   lastname: string.label('user lastname'),
   gender: bool.label('user gender'),
   age: number.label('user age')
};
```